# plotting text in R at absolute position

Tags: r, text, plot

is there a way to plot text with the `text` command at a specific proportion of the max x and y values of the plot (`plot` command in R)? At 10% of max value of x  and 20% of max value of y? I can't specify them by normal  x and y coordinates because I am plotting several barcharts and the values changes.

Comment: If you have specific programming-related question, you should attach a code example. It will be easier to help you. If you plot the barcharts in a loop, then you can save the maximum/minimum values that will get plotted at each iteration of the loop. You can use those values to (a) set the limits for the x- and y-axes, and (b) to place the text in relation to those limits.

Answer (score 4):

[These four lines](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Specifying-relative-position-of-text-in-a-plot-td849431.html) for code written in R are very practical. Simply save the current cordinates, establish a new coordinate grid for your preferred code, then change it back to the original cordinates:

```
usr <- par("usr")   # save old user/default/system coordinates
par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1)) # new relative user coordinates
text(0.1, 0.5, "Some text", adj = 0)  # if that's what you want
par(usr = usr) # restore original user coordinates
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is super useful in so many different applications where x and y coordinates are used but not always known a priori.  

This can become even more concise if you don't mind adding the annotation, etc. at the end of your plot:  the first and last lines can be omitted since you don't need to preserve the original coords.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: See the comment below this, that's a better answer.

Not directly, but you can store the max and min of your variables, then do something like:

```
plot(..., ylim = c(miny, maxy), xlim = c(minx, maxx) 
#you can play around with where you want to set those limits
text(x=(minx + 0.3*(maxx-minx)), ...)
```

Comment: You can get the axis limits of the current plot with ``par("usr")``.

Answer (score 0):

David's answer is great, but it didn't work for me with log-scale axes. Here's what I did instead:

```
placelabel <- function(label, x, y, ...) {
    xlim <- par("usr")[1:2]
    ylim <- par("usr")[3:4]

    xpos <- xlim[1] + x*(xlim[2] - xlim[1])
    ypos <- ylim[1] + y*(ylim[2] - ylim[1])

    if(par("xlog")) xpos <- 10^xpos
    if(par("ylog")) ypos <- 10^ypos
    
    text(xpos, ypos, label, ...)
}

plot(1, 1)
placelabel("topleft", 0.05, 0.95, adj = c(0, 1), font = 2)

## Should be in the same place
plot(1, 1, log = "xy")
placelabel("topleft", 0.05, 0.95, adj = c(0, 1), font = 2)
```